# Never ending MySQL query during data import

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a data import routine from a set of CSV files into my main database and am stuck with this particular set of data.  I've used LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to dump the CSV data into my table, feed_hcp_leasenote:

```
CREATE TABLE `feed_hcp_leasenote` (
 `BLDGID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `LEASID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `NOTEDATE` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `REF1` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `REF2` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `LASTDATE` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `USERID` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `NOTETEXT` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `tempid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 PRIMARY KEY (`tempid`),
 KEY `BLDGID` (`BLDGID`),
 KEY `LEASID` (`LEASID`),
 KEY `REF1` (`REF1`),
 KEY `NOTEDATE` (`NOTEDATE`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=65002 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I'm trying to import this data into two tables, lease_notes and customfield_data.  lease_notes only stores a unique ID value, the note itself, and the lid which links it to the lease table.  customfield_data stores a variety of data for system- and user-created fields, with each record linked to another table via the linkid field.  Here's the lease_note table:

```
CREATE TABLE `lease_notes` (
 `lnid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `notetext` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Lease ID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`lnid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

And the customfield_data table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customfield_data` (
 `cfdid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `data_int` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `data_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `data_smtext` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `data_lgtext` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `data_numeric` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `linkid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ID value of specific item',
 `cfid` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Custom field ID',
 PRIMARY KEY (`cfdid`),
 KEY `data_smtext` (`data_smtext`(333)),
 KEY `linkid` (`linkid`),
 KEY `cfid` (`cfid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The query that is getting stuck is as follows:

```
SELECT NOTEDATE, REF1, REF2, LASTDATE, USERID, feed_hcp_leasenote.NOTETEXT, leases.lid, lease_notes.lnid
FROM feed_hcp_leasenote
JOIN customfield_data mrileaseid ON feed_hcp_leasenote.LEASID = mrileaseid.data_smtext AND mrileaseid.cfid = ?
JOIN leases ON mrileaseid.linkid = leases.lid
JOIN suites ON leases.sid = suites.sid
JOIN floors ON suites.fid = floors.fid
JOIN customfield_data coid ON floors.bid = coid.linkid AND coid.cfid = ? AND coid.data_smtext = feed_hcp_leasenote.BLDGID
JOIN customfield_data status ON leases.lid = status.linkid AND status.cfid = ? AND status.data_smtext <> ?
LEFT JOIN lease_notes ON leases.lid = lease_notes.lid
LEFT JOIN customfield_data notedate ON lease_notes.lnid = notedate.linkid AND notedate.data_date = feed_hcp_leasenote.NOTEDATE AND notedate.cfid = ?
LEFT JOIN customfield_data ref1 ON lease_notes.lnid = ref1.linkid AND ref1.data_smtext = feed_hcp_leasenote.REF1 AND ref1.cfid = ?
```

My goal with this is to return all records in feed_hcp_leasenote and, depending on whether or not lease_notes.lnid is null, insert or update the records as needed (nulls would be inserts, not nulls would be updates.)  The problem is that the provided data uses a combination of 4 fields to determine uniqueness: BLDGID, LEASID, NOTEDATE, and REF1.  A note will not exist without a proper BLDGID and LEASID (translated in my query to a valid  *lid*.  It can match an existing record with a valid lid, NOTEDATE, and REF1, but if those don't match then I can assume it's a new record.

If I chop off all of the LEFT JOINs and the lease_notes.lnid from the SELECT, it executes properly and gives me all records.  Since I couldn't get my original query to work I played with the idea of cycling all results and performing **another** SELECT to see if the notedate and ref1 matched.  If not, I INSERTed, otherwise UPDATE.  While this approach works it can only process about 20 records per second which is a problem when I'm dealing with 30,000 at a crack.

Since I got asked about it in a previous question, here's an EXPLAIN of my query:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  status  ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     cfid    4   const   934     Using where
1   SIMPLE  mrileaseid  ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     linkid  5   rl_hpsi.status.linkid   19  Using where
1   SIMPLE  leases  eq_ref  PRIMARY,sid     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.mrileaseid.linkid   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  suites  eq_ref  PRIMARY,fid     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.leases.sid  1    
1   SIMPLE  floors  eq_ref  PRIMARY,bid     PRIMARY     4   rl_hpsi.suites.fid  1    
1   SIMPLE  feed_hcp_leasenote  ref     BLDGID,LEASID   LEASID  153     rl_hpsi.mrileaseid.data_smtext  19  Using where
1   SIMPLE  coid    ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     data_smtext     1002    rl_hpsi.feed_hcp_leasenote.BLDGID   10  Using where
1   SIMPLE  lease_notes     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    15000    
1   SIMPLE  notedate    ref     linkid,cfid     linkid  5   rl_hpsi.lease_notes.lnid    24   
1   SIMPLE  ref1    ref     data_smtext,linkid,cfid     data_smtext     1002    rl_hpsi.feed_hcp_leasenote.REF1     10
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Comment: I may have missed something cause I wasn't following all of that clearly, but `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` seems like the syntax you want to follow, google that phrase to learn more about it.

Comment: Well, unfortunately I won't have duplicate keys because the source data doesn't have a unique ID field that I can use to compare.

Comment: Add one. You import the data and you know the rules that make a record unique, it seems trivial to add a unique key to the table.

Comment: I did, actually -- tempid is the last field in my imported table.  However, since it's autogenerated on import it doesn't match the ID field(s) of the data that it will be added to or replacing.  I added that field with the thought of doing a SELECT WHERE tempid NOT IN query, but that works as well as this one -- not at all.

Comment: I'm not suggesting to add a new field, but to add a new index. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueTestIndex ON feed_hcp_leasenote (BLDGID,LEASID,NOTEDATE,REF1)`

Comment: Ahh, I see -- and then I assume I'd need to store that unique index in the lease_note table as well?  Since those values are split among multiple tables I imagine that trying to query those on the fly would lead to the same problem I'm experiencing now.

Comment: yeah, it's duplicating data for now, but once your import is complete you can drop those columns

Comment: Makes sense -- thanks a bunch!  Mind entering your CREATE UNIQUE INDEX comment as an answer and I'll mark it answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our comments:

The answer is to add the columns that make an entry unique to your destination table and create a compound unique key on them. Then when inserting to that table use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to prevent duplicate data. When the insert is complete you can drop those columns if they are no longer necessary, to prevent storing data in multiple tables.